# Best way to enrich when source context is anything but a specific value

Tags: logging, serilog

When building up programmatically a `LoggerConfiguration` to be used later, I wanted and succeeded to constrain the using of an enricher for all source context values *except* one (Global.asax from an old webforms website).

But it seems to me like this moves away (I don't like that `Invoke` call) from what I think the Serilog library intended as practice through it's quite nice and elegant fluent API:

```cs
private static LoggerConfiguration GetBasicLoggerConfig()
{
    return new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .Enrich.When(
            logEvent => !Matching.FromSource("ASP.global_asax").Invoke(logEvent),
            enrichmentConfig => enrichmentConfig.WithAnyKindOfEnricher());
}
```

I use this logic to exclude a list of enrichers from running when out of context and only want them to execute when inside the page's lifecycle. But regardless of this case, as I'm going to apply this approach in other places, I want to keep it clean&short and *I am mostly interested in the concept itself - "enrich by excluding a particular context".*

I have looked for ways like `WhenNot` or `NotMatching` to express "negation" / "exclusion" and didn't manage to find them in the library. Tried with other methods offered by the static class `Matching` but to no avail. The project is big and I'd like to personalize the whole logging depending on various contexts (so ending up using a series of `Enrich.When()`s - and with a big list of enrichers, obtaining the complete config tree with several "exclude only one context" parts seems ugly/messy).

Of course, centrally declaring a default value for context as in the example below does not cut it because there will be different contexts declared through `.ForContext<T>()` and all of them but one must be "catched" in the condition for enriching.

```cs
// this does not cut it
return new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .Enrich.WithProperty(Serilog.Core.Constants.SourceContextPropertyName, "default")
    .Enrich.When(Matching.FromSource("default"),
        enrichmentConfig => enrichmentConfig.WithAnyKindOfEnricher());
```

Hope that I managed to explain what I'm trying to achieve. (The lambda parameter names are long for clarity reasons)

So, did I miss something or is there another approach? How to best achieve this "enriching by exclusion"?

**later edits:**
- Forgot to mention that I log only to files (using file sink).
- Not looking to integrate Seq (I know about its advantages), at least not in the near future.

Comment: Why not avoid the problem entirely making the enrichers store `null` or `default(T)` if the information to enrich is not available or doesn't apply? It's a lot easier to analyze logs when they all have the same number of columns...

Comment: @CaioProiete (Sorry, forgot to mention that I log only to file) This is a good recommendation for some cases, yes, I thought about this a bit but I've already advanced into a structure of log where I print in files sets of properties with custom texts, each set on it's own line - found was the sanest this way. Maybe I should disperse sets to separate files. But I feel that having it all-in-one place when locating a time interval / timestamp in log to scan through is more efficient, less straining on heavy troubleshooting. I'm curious about the concept I mentioned, if it is achievable somehow.

Comment: Basically, I'm creating different logs with very different data, from different zones in the project. But doesn't seem fun to correlate multiple logs by timeline every time I test / troubleshoot. And now I see that this became two different questions (one theoretical - that concept ; the other practical - to arrive at a solution with emitting high volume/high diversity of data) from a single application. I know the project has design issues, should've been modularized differently, eh.

Comment: The syntax is a bit patchy, here - `Enrich.When(Matching.FromSource("X"), ...)` shows how the fluent `Matching` feature is supposed to work, but it's missing `Not()` - will look into adding it :-)

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt I did thought about that earlier this month :), how cool would be to have a `.WhenNot()` / `.Not()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Serilog.Filters.Expressions*](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-filters-expressions) is nicer for this:

```cs
        // dotnet add package serilog.filters.expressions
        .Enrich.When(
            "SourceContext <> 'ASP.global_asax'"),
            enrichmentConfig => enrichmentConfig.WithAnyKindOfEnricher());
```

Comment: Good alternative, the plugin is powerful, but I want my logic as close to "strong typed" as possible. So I'm trying to stay away from expressions as strings.

Comment: Property values in Serilog aren't strongly-typed; it's more likely that hand-rolled code will fail unexpectedly in cases where `SourceContext` isn't scalar or isn't a string.

Answer (score 2):

⚠️ the code **below is simplified and incorrect**. based on comment by Nicholas Blumhardt, there would be a some extra null check / casting involved.

The correct condition would look like

```cs
logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue("SourceContext", out var ctx) && ctx is ScalarValue sv && sv.Value is string s && s.StartsWith("blah")
```

(but could be extracted to an extension method somehow if we wanted)

---

If you are defining your logging configuration as code (and not from a JSON file or AppSettings), then, I'd suggest you just write plain C# code, and do something along the lines of :

```cs
private static LoggerConfiguration GetBasicLoggerConfig()
{
    return new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .Enrich.When(
            logEvent => logEvent.Properties["SourceContext"].StartsWith("blah")
              //add all the complexity you want in here
              || logEvent.Properties["SourceContext"].EndsWith("foo"), 
            enrichmentConfig => enrichmentConfig.WithAnyKindOfEnricher());
}
```

It might be easier to express the complex conditions you want to use.

If you are feeling uneasy about the *magic string* `"SourceContext"`, it is also available as a constant from `Serilog.Core.Constants.SourceContextPropertyName`.

If `logEvent.Properties["SourceContext"]` feels a little verbose, you could make it a bit more readable by defining an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), for instance :

```cs
public static string GetSourceContext(this LogEvent logEvent){
 return logEvent.Properties["SourceContext"];
}
```

Comment: This approach is not short but enables me to filter in any way I want - including "anything but these two values". This while not having the logic in a string.

Comment: Hallo :-) - `logEvent.Properties["SourceContext"]` isn't a string, and isn't always present, so the indexer may fail, and `StartsWith()` can't be called on the result. Expanding this out you'll need `logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue("SourceContext", out var ctx) && ctx is ScalarValue sv && sv.Value is string s && s.StartsWith("blah")`. It's a valid approach, but easier to get wrong than the filter expression.

Comment: thanks for the heads up @ni 
Indeed I didn't test that code, and I guess we would need a few null checks and all to make it work fine.

Comment: Maybe I'm stretching it but, keeping the vote-up because I think that most part of that jazzy hand-rolled code - well tested - fits snugly into that `GetSourceContext` extension method and thus enables a decent alternative (though longer, not concise) to anyone not wanting to use `Serilog.Filters.Expressions` for whatever bizarre reasons :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that involves a bit less custom code than my previous answer would be to use the features offered by [`Serilog.Filters.Matching`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/70624912bf79cf0406516d57c0fc225d783d281f/src/Serilog/Filters/Matching.cs).

```cs
// snip... probably need some usings for `Serilog.Filters`
// ...

private static bool ShouldEnrichForThisSourceContext(string sourceContext)
{
  // ⚠️ sourceContext is possibly null
  return sourceContext.StartsWith("whatever") || sourceContext.Contains("xxx");
}

private static LoggerConfiguration GetBasicLoggerConfig()
{
    return new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .Enrich.When(
            Matching.WithProperty<string>(
              Constants.SourceContextPropertyName, 
              ShouldEnrichForThisSourceContext), 
            enrichmentConfig => enrichmentConfig.WithAnyKindOfEnricher());
}
```

I don't have access to a working .NET IDE right now, so it might not quite compile, but that would be the idea.